# Why can't Mathematica evaluate the limit of this hypergeometric function? Is there any way to find the answer?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have the following function

```
    f = 1/Gamma[(1 + d)/2] \[Pi]^(
  1/2 (-1 + d)) ((
    Sqrt[2] (-1 + d) r^5 (2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 
      1/(-4 + 2 d), 1 + 1/(-4 + 2 d), -(1/2) r^(-4 + 2 d)])/(
    2 r^4 + r^(2 d)) + (
    r^(-1 + d) (6 - 4 d + (
       Sqrt[2] (2 - 3 d + d^2) r^(
        2 + d) (2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (3 - 2 d)/(
         4 - 2 d), (7 - 4 d)/(
         4 - 2 d), -(1/2) r^(-4 + 2 d)])/((-3 + 2 d) (2 r^4 + r^(
          2 d))) + 
       2 (-1 + d) Log[(2 r^d)/(r^d + r^2 Sqrt[2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)])]))/(
    2 (-1 + d)))
```

Mathematica can not evaluate the limit of $f$ when $r$ goes to infinity.

```
Limit[f, r -> Infinity, Assumptions -> d >= 4]
```

Is there anyway that this limit can be evaluated by Mathematica?
Note that if I first put $d=4$ or $5$ or ... and then take the limit, Mathematica find the answer.

```
Limit[f /. d -> 4, r -> Infinity]
-(2/9) 2^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Pi]] (9 Gamma[-(3/4)] + 4 Gamma[1/4]) Gamma[5/4]
```

But I need the general relation as a function of $d$.

Comment: `Limit[f, r -> Infinity, Assumptions -> d > 1]` results in `ConditionalExpression[\[Infinity], d < 3/2]` and  both `Limit[f, r -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> d > 3/2 && d \[Element] Integers]`and`Limit[f, r -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> d > 3/2]` return the input.

Comment: `Table[Limit[f, r -> Infinity, Assumptions -> d > 1], {d, 2, 7}]` results in `{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], -(2/9) 2^(3/4)
   Sqrt[\[Pi]] (9 Gamma[-(3/4)] + 4 Gamma[1/4]) Gamma[5/4], -((\[Pi]^(
   3/2) (8 Gamma[-(2/3)] Gamma[7/6] + 25 Gamma[1/3] Gamma[7/6] - 
     11 Gamma[1/6] Gamma[4/3]))/(4 2^(1/3))), -(2/225) 2^(5/8) \[Pi]^(
  3/2) (150 Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[9/8] + 513 Gamma[3/8] Gamma[9/8] - 
    155 Gamma[1/8] Gamma[11/8]), -((\[Pi]^(
   5/2) (18 Gamma[-(3/5)] Gamma[11/10] + 65 Gamma[2/5] Gamma[11/10] - 
     15 Gamma[1/10] Gamma[7/5]))/(18 2^(2/5)))}`, so general formula is unclear.

Comment: And such a general formula may not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f[d_, r_] = 1/Gamma[(1 + d)/2] π^(1/2 (-1 + d))((Sqrt[2] (-1 + d) r^5 (2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/(-4 + 2 d), 1 + 1/(-4 + 2 d), -(1/2) r^(-4 + 2 d)])/(2 r^4 + r^(2 d)) + (r^(-1 + d) (6 - 4 d + (Sqrt[2] (2 - 3 d + d^2) r^(2 + d) (2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (3 - 2 d)/(4 - 2 d), (7 - 4 d)/(4 - 2 d), -(1/2) r^(-4 + 2 d)])/((-3 + 2 d) (2 r^4 + r^(2 d))) + 2 (-1 + d) Log[(2 r^d)/(r^d + r^2 Sqrt[2 + r^(-4 + 2 d)])]))/(2 (-1 + d)));

F[d_] := F[d] = Limit[f[d, r], r -> ∞]

Table[F[d] == -((2^(1/2 (-3 + 1/(-2 + d))) π^(-1 + d/2) *
                Gamma[-((-1 + d)/(2 (-2 + d)))] *
                Gamma[1/(-4 + 2 d)])/Gamma[(1 + d)/2]), {d, 4, 20}] // FullSimplify
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}    *)
```

So it looks like the limit is

$$
-\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{d-2}-3\right)} \pi ^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{d-1}{2 (d-2)}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 d-4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)}
$$

Comment: `FullSimplify[{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], -(2/9) 2^(3/4)    Sqrt[\[Pi]] (9 Gamma[-(3/4)] + 4 Gamma[1/4]) Gamma[5/4], -((\[Pi]^(    3/2) (8 Gamma[-(2/3)] Gamma[7/6] + 25 Gamma[1/3] Gamma[7/6] -       11 Gamma[1/6] Gamma[4/3]))/(4 2^(1/3))), -(2/225) 2^(5/8) \[Pi]^(   3/2) (150 Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[9/8] + 513 Gamma[3/8] Gamma[9/8] -      155 Gamma[1/8] Gamma[11/8]), -((\[Pi]^(    5/2) (18 Gamma[-(3/5)] Gamma[11/10] + 65 Gamma[2/5] Gamma[11/10] -       15 Gamma[1/10] Gamma[7/5]))/(18 2^(2/5)))}]` (see my comment to the question) results in

Comment: `{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], -(4/3) 2^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[5/4], -((\[Pi]^(3/2)
    Gamma[-(2/3)] Gamma[1/6])/(4 2^(1/3))), -(2/15) 2^(5/8) \[Pi]^(
  3/2) Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[1/8], -((
  5 \[Pi]^(5/2) Gamma[-(3/5)] Gamma[11/10])/(6 2^(2/5)))}`

Comment: Unfortunately, `FindSequenceFunction[{-(4/3) 2^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(3/4)] Gamma[
    5/4], -((\[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[-(2/3)] Gamma[1/6])/(4 2^(1/3))), -(2/
      15) 2^(5/8) \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[-(5/8)] Gamma[
    1/8], -((5 \[Pi]^(5/2) Gamma[-(3/5)] Gamma[11/10])/(6 2^(2/5)))},
  d]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 I figured out the `Gamma` and $\pi$ dependencies manually (by inspection) and then used `FindSequenceFunction` on the remaining factor.

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction` leaves much to be desired. For example, `FindSequenceFunction[{-1, 4, -9, 16, -25, 36}, n]` returns the input.

Comment: Nice, this is the correct answer. Pity that MA cannot do it automatically.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

`Asymptotic` evaluates to

```
asy=Asymptotic[f, r -> Infinity]
(*ConditionalExpression[ ..., 0 < d < 1]*)
```

and restricts parameter to `0<d<1`.

```
Simplify[asy, 0 < d < 1]
(*(Sqrt[2] (-1 + d) \[Pi]^(1/2 (-1 + d))r)/Gamma[(1 + d)/2]*)
```

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2} (d-1) \pi ^{\frac{d-1}{2}} r}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)}
$$

shows `asy~r`!  The limit doesn't exist for  `r -> Infinity`!

Comment: Thank you. The assumption is that d>=4.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the restriction `d>= 4`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Asymptotic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic) with an assumption about `d` ought to do the job (as in Ulrich's answer):

```
Asymptotic[f, r->Infinity, Assumptions->d>4]
```

But it takes too long. On the other hand, it looks like you can help Mathematica by shifting the `d` variable:

```
asym = Asymptotic[
    FullSimplify[f /. d -> z + 4], 
    r -> Infinity, 
    Assumptions -> z > 0
];
```

Unfortunately, the output still depends on `r`:

```
FreeQ[asym, r]
```

> False

However, if you repeat using [`Asymptotic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic) on the above output:

```
asym2 = Asymptotic[asym, r->Infinity, Assumptions -> z > 0];
```

The output no longer depends on `r`:

```
FreeQ[asym2, r]
```

> True

Shifting back and simplifying yields:

```
r = FullSimplify[asym2 /. z -> d - 4]
```

> -((2^(1/2 (-3 + 1/(-2 + d))) π^(-1 + d/2)
> Gamma[1/(2 (-2 + d))] Gamma[-((-1 + d)/(2 (-2 + d)))])/Gamma[(1 + d)/2])

This is equivalent to Roman's answer:

```
Simplify @ Equal[
    r,
    -((2^(1/2 (-3+1/(-2+d))) π^(-1+d/2)*Gamma[-((-1+d)/(2 (-2+d)))]*Gamma[1/(-4+2 d)])/Gamma[(1+d)/2])
]
```

> True

Comment: Nice answer. In my Mathematica version, doesn't work Asymptotic for asym, but taking the limit works well.